# .NET CORE 6 WPF and Class Library versioning noob questions

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core, versioning

This is probably a very basic question, but after reading about it I am still confused...

Ok, so I have an WPF app, MyApp, that uses my class library MyLib.
The coding is almost done now, and I am about to start deploying it to my customers, but as obviously both the WPF app and the class library will need
improvements/new features in future, I want to get all this versioning thing right from the begining.
(I have no experience on this as I have always code to my own use only, so I never needed to mess with version numbers etc).
Now, I want to have the the typical "About" windows (accessible from WPF app menu) and there I want to show both the app version and the library version used (and also the build time).

So I have done some research thinking it would be an easy task, but the more I read about it, the more confused I am...

First, I have found there are 3 different version numbers (File Version, Assembly Version and Package Version) that I am still trying to wrap my head around.

Then, if I access (inside Visual Studio) the project properties for the WPF app, I can see in section Package > General there are specified version numbers for Package (1.0.0), Assembly (1.0.0.0) and File (1.0.0.0). But I have no idea where are those numbers coming from, as in the project file I can't see any reference to them...
Besides that, that Package version number in the project properties, shows both an input text with something like "$(VersionPrefix)", then below it, a non-editable 1.0.0. I have no idea what this means. In the other 2 version numbers, the text boxes are empty) (and why in package version, it shows 3 parts, 1.0.0, but the others show 4 parts, 1.0.0.0).

Please could somebody enlighten me in all this, and advice on how should I manage it?

Comment: What is your build process? Do you have an App Installer?

Comment: Just for the records: You are aware of [Versioning in C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/versioning) and [Library Guidance - Versioning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/library-guidance/versioning) ?

Comment: The file, assembly and package versions should most likely be the same for a simple application. You should probably also use some Continuous Integration or build system to keep track of at least build number.